# When I try to update a row, I get an foreign key error. Why?

Tags: c#

```
throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
```

This is the error i get when I try to update a row. 
I use foreign keys to get the type id from a different table. When I update this, I get the error. Updating the name works just fine.

This is the code I use to update.

```
            hetVoer.Naam = NaamTekst.Text;
        hetVoer.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(TypeTekst.SelectedValue);
        hetVoer.Prijs = Decimal.Parse(PrijsTekst.Text);

        var item = (Voer)VoerTekst.SelectedItem;
        var delItem = from Voer in db.Voers
                      where Voer.Vid == item.Vid
                      select Voer;


        db.Voers.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
        db.Voers.InsertOnSubmit(hetVoer);
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

Im using C#.

Answer (score 1):

Try submitting your changes after the delete, you need to save the database before re-adding the new entry.

```
        hetVoer.Naam = NaamTekst.Text;
    hetVoer.TypeId = Convert.ToInt32(TypeTekst.SelectedValue);
    hetVoer.Prijs = Decimal.Parse(PrijsTekst.Text);

    var item = (Voer)VoerTekst.SelectedItem;
    var delItem = from Voer in db.Voers
                  where Voer.Vid == item.Vid
                  select Voer;


    db.Voers.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    db.Voers.InsertOnSubmit(hetVoer);
    db.SubmitChanges();
```